# Pasar una variable con este código

Tags: javascript

Quiero pasar la variable `id_proyecto` con ese código que se actualiza cada ciertos segundos:

```
function tiempoReal()
    {
        var ide_proyecto = "<?php echo $ide ;?>";
        var tabla = $.ajax({
            url:'./load_ajax/seg.php',
            dataType:'text',
            async:false
        }).responseText;

        document.getElementById("seg").innerHTML = tabla;
    }
    setInterval(tiempoReal, 5000);
```

Comment: ¿Cual variable `id_proyecto`?

Answer (score 1):

Te falta la propiedad `data` ya que con esta es con la que especificas lo que quieres enviar.

```js
function tiempoReal()
    {
        var id_proyecto = "<?php echo $ide ;?>";
        var tabla = $.ajax({
            url:'./load_ajax/seg.php',
            dataType:'text',
            data: {id : id_proyecto}
            async:false,
        }).responseText;

        document.getElementById("seg").innerHTML = tabla;
    }
    setInterval(tiempoReal, 5000);
```